# How to retrieve Token for API calls in cypress

Tags: javascript, jwt, cypress

Due to a lack of knowledge in JS, I do face with below problem.
I do automation testing with cypress and for external API endpoints, I need to use Dynamic Token that expires every 3600 secs.
I did some short research and find out that, for reaching to JWT Token I will need 1st SSO login (that my app has). Then use the below script.
But I don't know what to do after this.

```
 it('the value of JWT Token should exist in localStorage', () => {
        cy.getLocalStorage('JWT_DATA').then(lsData => {
            cy.log('the token', lsData); // I get JWT Token in here
        });
    });
```

The result of this script is only printing the TOKEN.
But I need to store it somehow and then be able to reuse it for every different API endpoint call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Cypress.env` for this. Then you can use the token throughout the test anywhere.

```js
it('the value of JWT Token should exist in localStorage', () => {
  cy.getLocalStorage('JWT_DATA').then((lsData) => {
    cy.log('the token', lsData) // I get JWT Token in here
    Cypress.env('token', lsData)
  })
})
```

To use it, you can do

```js
Cypress.env('token')
```